# show balance stock

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query which returns stock details as shown below in SQL Server 2008

[image]

On a particular date the stock balance for the items A00001 and A00002 are 40, 120 respectively. So I want to distribute that values as shown below(order by ItemCode,DateofReceipt desc)

[image]

Can any one help me how I can update the first query results(I can store this values to a temporary table, if needed) to get the stock balance as in the second table without using cursor?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
declare @tb table (itemCode varchar(10),DateofReceipt date,invno varchar(10), inqty int)
    insert into @tb (itemcode,dateofReceipt,invno,inqty) values
    ('A00001','20150401','Inv01',100),
    ('A00001','20150410','Inv03',50),
    ('A00002','20150405','Inv02',100),
    ('A00002','20150415','Inv04',50)

    declare @stock table(item varchar(10),qty int)
    insert into @stock (item,qty) values
    ('A00001',50),('A00002',120)

    ;with cte as (select *,case when row_number() over(partition by itemCode order by DateofReceipt desc )=1 then qty else 0 end as stk,
    row_number() over(order by itemcode, DateofReceipt desc) as rno
    from @tb t inner join @stock s on t.itemCode=s.item),
    ct1 (stock,bls,rno) as (select case when stk<=inqty then stk else inqty end as stock,case when stk<=inqty then 0 else stk-inqty end as bls,rno from cte where rno=1
    union all select case when stk+bls<=inqty then stk+bls else inqty end as stock,case when stk+bls<=inqty then 0 else stk+bls-inqty end as bls,cte.rno from ct1 inner join cte on ct1.rno+1=cte.rno)

    select itemcode,dateofReceipt,invno,inqty,stock from ct1 inner join cte on ct1.rno =cte.rno
```